# Errors on subscribing to groups resource on MSGraph beta endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

Having a 500 Internal Error when calling MSGraph beta endpoint to subscribe to resource "groups"

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://prod.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/chopped",
  "resource": "groups",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-01-14T03:36:37.8354290Z",
  "clientState": "its_me_hi"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: InternalServerError; Reason: Internal Server Error]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "fd08e940-bf54-44e4-bac8-aa3e53995e0d",
      "date": "2018-01-11T05:07:43"
    }
  }
}

request-id: fd08e940-bf54-44e4-bac8-aa3e53995e0d
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Australia SouthEast","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"MEL"}}
```

A few more notes:

1. My notificationUrl is called and I returned a validationToken.  When I don't return a token, the subscription fails with a correct check.
2. My expiration datetime, if set beyond 3 days, also fails correctly with a expiration too long check.

It seems the webhook's nearly set up, and then something failed afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've identified the issue. It should be fixed - please try again.